# C# Nesting asynchronous methods

Tags: c#, async-await

is it possible to do something like this or is it dangerous/bad practice?  If it's not good, what would be another way to go about it?

```
void methodA () 
{
    while (something) {
        // do stuff
        methodB();
    }
}

async Task methodB() 
{
     bool b = await methodC();
     // do something with b
}

async Task<bool> methodC() 
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for `methodA` to be able to do stuff while `methodC` is waiting on IO.  So with this I'm hoping that `methodC` will return to `methodB` while busy and since `methodB` awaits the answer, it will return to `methodA`, where `methodA` can keep working on stuff and perhaps call `methodB` once again

Comment: What exactly is `something` and why are you not `await`ing the call to `methodB`?

Comment: Not only is this not bad, it's kinda the whole point to Async.  After all Task.Delay is simply a methods that's being awaited for in another method (or in other words, Task.Delay does nothing you couldn't do as a C# programmer).  That's not to say you can't make mistakes... async is another layer of complexity.

Comment: @JustinNiessner We have a thread that spins in a loop waiting for new messages, once it receives a message, it will send process some stuff and send it over to a server (async call, hence the task.delay) and I was wondering if it's okay to program it this way without introducing any bad stuff (e.g. deadlock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be perfectly acceptable for you not to wait for MethodB in MethodA (as long as you don't actually need MethodB to finish before you do other stuff in MethodA and you're careful to avoid race conditions). There are a few other options though.

You might want to look at [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx).

A second option that I like a lot here:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
while (something) {
        // do stuff
        // This doesn't actually wait for methodB - it just keeps going
        Task methodBTask = methodB();
        tasks.Add(methodBTask);
    }

// Wait for all of the tasks we started to complete
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
// ...
```

I think that this should do what you want and it won't be prone to race conditions. Basically, this'll start whatever action in MethodB however many times you want and then just wait for all of them to complete once they've all been "queued up."

Comment: sorry I had a typo, I did mean to call `methodC` but I do not mean to await `methodB` inside `methodA`, in fact, I want `methodA` to be able to call `methodB` again, even if the other call to `methodB` has not finished

Comment: @SvetAngelov I edited. My new sample should do exactly what you're looking for I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is standard practice.

```
async Task methodA()
{
    while (something)
    {
        Task b = methodB();
        // do stuff
        await b;
    }
}
```

The caveat is that you're introducing concurrency here, so you need to ensure you don't have any threading issues with B executing while A is executing.

Comment: they would be working on separate data.  It's just that at the moment, we were using `Task.Run` for this and I feel like since we are doing IO work it would make more sense to use async/await. Does it sound right?

Comment: Not sure what is the difference between your code and just  await methodB(); He doesn't use b anywhere. In his example b is boolean, in yours it's task. "Do stuff" will block loop here. Why is it upvoted? EJoshuaS answer is correct.